# I want to set the y axis to always be 20 units higher than the max y value.

Tags: python, plot, graph, axis

As this is matrix data, it is hard to say yvals = [1, 2, 3]. I need to know how to select max values from my dataset in order to ax.set_ylim(0,max(val)+20) or something to that effect.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Sets the size of the chart
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 7, 2

#Creates the dataframe
raw_data = {'plan_type': ['Total Annual Price', 'Total Annual Cost,     
Family'],
    'x':     [60, 30],
    'y':     [48, 16],
    'z':     [18, 28],
    'a':      [49, 13],
    'b':      [57, 16],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,
              columns = ['plan_type','x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b'])

#Plots the bars, adding desired colors
ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0, color=['#ffc000',"#305496", '#8ea9db', '#b4c6e7',     
'#D9E1F2'],
             width = 0.8 )
# Title String
plt.title("Average Annual Medical Cost Insurance per Employee",y=1.08)

# Subtitle string and postitioning
subtitle_string=("**xyz")
plt.suptitle(subtitle_string,fontsize=8, y=0.8)

#Adds data labels to top of bars
for p in ax.patches[0:]:
h = p.get_height()
x = p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.
if h != 0:
    ax.annotate("%g" % p.get_height()+'%', xy=(x,h), xytext=(0,4),     
rotation=0,
               textcoords="offset points", ha="center", va="bottom")

#Sets x-axis limits and margins
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, +1.5)
ax.margins(y=0)

# Set the Y Axis Limits
ax.set_ylim(0,(yvals+20))
ax.margins(y=0)

#Adds legend to the top of the page
ax.legend(ncol=len(df.columns), loc="Lower Left", bbox_to_anchor=    
(0,1.02,1,0.06),
      borderaxespad=0, mode="expand")

#Add labels to the x-axis
ax.set_xticklabels(df["plan_type"])

#shows the plot and prints it to
plt.show()
plt.savefig("PlanOffered.png")
```

Someone, please help, a quick fix I imagine. Filling space because apparently, I need more content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but you could generate the row-wise max of the column-wise max or vice versa:

```
ax.set_ylim(0,df[['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b']].max(axis=1).max(axis=0)+20)
```

Comment: you are awesome!